# How can I flash ClockWorkMod on my Samsung Galaxy Fit running froyo?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-fit

I was following instructions on xda-developers to install [a new ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1430889), then it linked to [these instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1339640) about installing CWM on Samsung GT-S5670. The problem is, there's a Warning there that says:

> I take no support for RFS file system So this Recovery will not work
>   for Stock ROM or Custom ROM that using RFS file system. Also this
>   Recovery will not work for froyo baseband

My device matches **both** conditions.
I did a `mount` and checked the output, both `/system` and `/cache` are RFS. And I'm running stock Android 2.2.1 JXKA4 baseband (And there's no official update from what I know).

Now, I searched everywhere, and found [someone who ported this to support RFS filesystems](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=24719114&postcount=1387). I'm not sure that's what I want though, because I will be installing an ext4 ROM.

I also read in the forums about people bricking their device with ROM Manager, as it is not currently supported... (and with the method I linked to also with android 2.2)

I guess I definitely need Odin, but can't find the right version (official or not) of CWM to flash? What do I risk trying to flash the one on xda-developers forum, most probably bricking right?

Or maybe should I use another recovery for my device?

**UPDATE**:
I just read [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1642627&highlight=all+in+one+guide). It seems there is not other way but to:

> First of all upgrade to Gingerbread via Kies/ODIN. Then, install CWM
>   via ODIN. Download any ROM and flash via CWM.

So, for CWM 5 on Samsung Galaxy Fit to work, you need to have Gingerbread flashed, and ad my phone has never had the Gingerbread official update, I think I will have to flash another stock ROM (another region), then flash CWM, then probably flash a custom ROM.
Additionally I thought I might install that RFS based CWM to backup stock ROM, then go on flashing a custom ROM.

I'll try it, and if it works, I'll post an answer and accept it.

Comment: You should be able to flash the recovery with Ext4 support and then immediately flash the ROM, but I don't know the details for sure.  You are unlikely to perma-brick unless you flash a bootloader, Odin-ing to stock should undo anything else.

Comment: @MatthewRead The problem is that I can't make a Nandroid backup before flashing CWM or similar, and I'd rather do that beforehand... I don't want to take any risk.

Comment: Odin is better than Nandroid, but I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, just in case this might help someone else:

- I tried flashing CWM 5 for RFS file systems via Odin. It's actually straightforward, and then the phone reboots normally. However, trying to get to the recovery mode fails. (I'm not sure how exactly, but it wouldn't work for me, I think it hanged at the recovery screen with android written on it).
- (I freaked out) Then I downloaded a stock ROM (indian, based on 2.3.6) from samfirmware. Flashed it through Odin again. The device reboots (and takes some time) and you're on 2.3.6!
- Then I flashed CWM 5 for Galaxy Fit (also from Odin) from the forums. It went smoothly. It will also boot into the stock ROM, and into the recovery.
- From there, I didn't really try to do a Nandroid backup. (I supposed it would fail).
- Then I formatted /data, /cache, ... Then moved the update zip file (the ROM) onto the SD card. And from recovery, installed it.

It's really not a big deal, if you're worried as I was. A simple backup of all your user data and apps via TitaniumBackup or similar, and your contacts synced to Google or exported to the SD in csv format, and you won't even feel the transition.